# Azure Pipelines Shell Script task not executing

Tags: bash, shell, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to execute a shell script that modifies some files in my source code as part of a build pipeline. The build runs on a private linux agent.

So I'm using the shell script task (I've also tried an inline bash task), my yaml looks like this:

```
- task: ShellScript@2
  inputs:
    scriptPath: analytics/set-base-image.bash
    args: $(analyticsBaseImage)
    failOnStandardError: true
```

And set-base-image.bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mkdir testDir
sudo sed -i -e "s/##branchBaseImagePlaceholder##/$1/g" Dockerfile-shiny
sudo sed -i -e "s/##branchBaseImagePlaceholder##/$1/g" Dockerfile-plumber
```

But nothing happens. I get debug output that looks like this:

```
##[debug]/bin/bash arg: /datadrive/agent1/_work/1/s/analytics/set-base-image.bash
##[debug]args=analytics-base
##[debug]/bin/bash arg: analytics-base
##[debug]failOnStandardError=true
##[debug]exec tool: /bin/bash
##[debug]Arguments:
##[debug]   /datadrive/agent1/_work/1/s/analytics/set-base-image.bash
##[debug]   analytics-base
[command]/bin/bash /datadrive/agent1/_work/1/s/analytics/set-base-image.bash analytics-base
/datadrive/agent1/_work/1/s/analytics
##[debug]rc:0
##[debug]success:true
##[debug]task result: Succeeded
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]Bash exited with return code: 0
```

testDir isn't created and the files aren't modified.

The script runs fine if I log onto the agent machine and run it there (after running chmod +x on the script file).

I've also tried an inline Bash task instead of a shell task (what the difference is isn't obvious anyway).

If I add commands to the script that don't require any privileges, like `echo` and `pwd`, these run fine, and I see the results in the debug. But mkdir and sed don't.